# Returning a list from database by making a request using stored procedure

Tags: c#

I want to return a list of data from database, I pass params to a stored procedure, it then returns results to a list

```
List<DataDetail> FetchData(GenRequest Request)
{
    List<DataDetail> details = new List<DataDetail>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        // con.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Gen", con); 

        con.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForcedATMAmt", ForcedATMAmt);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OthersValue", OthersValue);

        con.Close();

        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            DataDetailobj = new DataDetail();

            obj.AdditionalPremium = dr["AdditionalPremium"].ToString();
            obj.ATMLimit = dr["ATMLimit"].ToString();

            details.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    return details
}
```

I tried the approach in the code above but when I hover over `dr`, the `dr.HasRows` is false. any way I can return the data to a list without `DataRows`?

Comment: Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: **WHY** are you closing the connection **BEFORE** executing the command?? And why do `ExecuteReader` and then subsequently do a `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` - that basically unnecessarily selects the data twice.....

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: And also: you should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: thanks all. I used DataReader to get it working like :  
```SqlDataReader dr = null;
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {  
string premium = dr["AdditionalPremium"].ToString();
}```

Comment: and then I added the string values to a list object like ```premium.Add(listobject);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, when working with a database connection your order of operations is:

1. Open the database connection
2. Run your queries/commands
3. Close the database connection

In your case, it should go something like this:

```
    con.Open()
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Gen", con);
    // add parameters
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);​
    da.Fill(dt);
    // run your code to get values from da
    con.Close()
```

As a side note, I don't believe you need to call `cmd.ExecuteReader();` yourself, but that `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` will execute the command for you.